# Why would someone store multiple rows in one Cassandra row?

Tags: json, performance, cassandra

I'm looking for ways to store nested dynamic documents in Cassandra and found a presentation where they suggest to create only few rows and store in each row many JSON objects: https://speakerdeck.com/dzello/store-json-the-hard-way?slide=112

I understand the idea to create column names based on the property path, and I understand that concatenating smaller objects usually results in a higher throughput, but I just think that it's a lot of overhead.

Would the performance in C* with a single object stored per row be really so bad that it's worth to have this mess with creating lists? Is there maybe something I am missing about C*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In the Store Json the Hard Way slides it should be noted these are experts in Cassandra who are performing a great deal of ancillary compaction and tombstone clear-out outside of Cassandra's normal operations.*

Data locality is key to great performance and having multiple logical rows in a single C* partition is key to that. All of the CQL Schema definitions are aimed around making it easier for the developer to specify what data goes in the same partition.

For an example

```
CREATE TABLE soda_sold_per_store ( 
    store text, date timestamp, soda_name text, soda_count int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (store,date,soda_count,soda_name)
```

Describes a table where there is only a single Cassandra partition for every store and within that partition the information is sorted based on date then soda_count and finally on soda_name.

This means queries inquiring about the number of sodas sold in a particular store over time will be very fast (they only hit a single partition of contiguous data already sorted on disk.) Other queries would be very hard on this schema though, such as "What is the total number of soda's sold in all stores on a particular day?" A query involving all stores requires receiving data from all nodes with this table and the data is not going to be contiguous on disk. Cassandra imposes this kind of tradeoff, well modeled tables will be extremely fast but they can only be fast for certain queries. Luckily writes in Cassandra are very cheap so it is common practice to have multiple tables, each satisfying one of your high demand queries.